BlazorBootstrap PdfViewer loads PDF only once in .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app
In a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app a razor component renders a link of links such as:
<NavLink href="@($"PharmakaPdfViewer/{row.Id}")" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">...</NavLink>

Here's the code of the PharmakaPdfViewer component:
@page "/pharmakapdfviewer/{id}"

<h3>PharmakaPdfViewer @Id</h3>

<PdfViewer Class="mb-3" Url="@link" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    private string? link = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var serviceClient = new APIServiceClient();

        var dataRow = await serviceClient.GetDataRowAsync(Int32.Parse(Id));

        link = dataRow.Link;

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}

PdfViewer is this Blazor Bootstrap component , which loads the PDF file fetched by the link URL. The value of the link property is set in the overridden OnInitializedAsync, which calls a SOAP web service and gets back the URL of the pdf file corresponding to the provided Id, for example:
https://localhost:44360/Content/Sample.pdf

The first time, everything works fine and the pdf is shown.
But when I navigate back to the list of links and click another (or the same, for that matter), I always get the following error (in the DevTools Console) and the PdfViewer remains empty as shown in the screenshot:
Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url
Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url
    at Module.getDocument (https://0.0.0.0/_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/pdfjs-4.0.379.min.js:21:46398)
    at Module.initialize (https://0.0.0.0/_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.pdf.js:202:11)
    at https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:3050
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at g.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:3007)
    at https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:48020
    at EventTarget.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:7:62)
    at EmbeddedBrowserWebView.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:43835)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSObjectReferenceExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSObjectReference jsObjectReference, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at BlazorBootstrap.PdfViewerJsInterop.InitializeAsync(Object objRef, String elementId, Double scale, Double rotation, String url)
   at BlazorBootstrap.PdfViewer.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)


Any idea why this is happening and how can it be fixed?
UPDATE:
I chose the following implementation to force the component to re-render without complaining about string.Empty or null:
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link))
{
    <PdfViewer Class="mb-3" Url="@link" />
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    private string? link;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Set link to null to force removal of the pdf viewer
        link = null;

        StateHasChanged();

        var serviceClient = new APIServiceClient();

        var dataRow = await serviceClient.GetDataRowAsync(Int32.Parse(Id));

        link = dataRow.Link;        
    }
}

That seems to do the trick.


Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url

I can reproduce the error when I set the link as string.Empty. And according to the error message, the link is invalid.
I see you used the async task to get the Url. So you can try to use StateHasChanged(); after you get the Url:
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var serviceClient = new APIServiceClient();

        var dataRow = await serviceClient.GetDataRowAsync(Int32.Parse(Id));

        link = dataRow.Link;
        
        StateHasChanged();
    }


@liyun-zhang-msft Indeed, when link is empty or null the error occurs. I tried StateHasChanged() without success. Also, I tried to assign link to the location of a blank pdf file so that the viewer could render that initially without complaining about empty/null. It didn't work either. It looks like viewer component is initialized only once... somehow...

@liyun-zhang-msft I came up with a solution, which is based on your answer. I've updated my question accordingly. Thank you for your answer.

You are welcome. Glad to know you have resolved this proble. In addition, it is similar as this case: OnInitializedAsync() in blazor.
